# Loss of information when merging parameters in maximum likelihood fit

Tags: maximum-likelihood, information-theory

I have a complex measurement with many data and several parameters to measures, $\mu_i$ using maximum likelihood. The estimated parameters have very large errors estimated from the likelihood and large correlation.

So, the idea is to merge some parameters, measuring sums or difference of some, for example if the are very negatively correlated to measure their difference: $\eta_1=\mu_1+\mu_2$. So at the end the number of estimated parameters is reduced.

How can I measure the loss of information between the two schemes maybe from the two covariance matrixes and the linear relation from to set of parameters?